# For what function of $\theta$ is the tangent of the mean equal to the cosine of the half difference of values around $\theta=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, symmetry

I would like to find a function $f(\theta)$ on the domain $\frac{-\pi}{2} \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$ for which $$ \tan \left( \frac{f(\theta) +f(-\theta))}{2}\right) = \cos \left( \frac{f(\theta) - f(-\theta))}{2}\right)$$
I know several things about the function:

- it is monotonically increasing and concave over this domain
- $f(\frac{-\pi}{2})=\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $f(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $f(\frac{-\pi}{4})=0$
- $f'(\frac{-\pi}{2})=\infty$ and $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$
- more generally the function has diagonal symmetry (across $y=-\theta$)

The function is similar in form but not identical to a Lame curve $$ y = -\sqrt[n]{{\pi}^n - x^n}$$ for $n=\log_2{(1+\sqrt{5})}-1$ and $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi$

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me that there should be a unique solution to your problem.

Let us introduce the symmetric function $S(\theta) = (f(\theta)+f(-\theta))/2$ and the anti-symmetric function $A(\theta) = (f(\theta)-f(-\theta))/2$. Then your equation states that $$tan(S(\theta)) = cos(A(\theta))$$

This is a not very restrictive relation between $S$ and $A$. It has solution $S(\theta) = tan^{-1}(cos(A(\theta))$. So we can choose a suitable $A(\theta)$, then evaluate the matching $S(\theta)$ and finally decompose into $f(\theta)$ and $f(-\theta)$.

Comment: But is there a unique solution to the problem that meets the other criteria listed in the question?

Comment: You wrote "I know several things about the function". It was not clear to me that these things were meant as strict demands. But if you put it like this, such a function may exist but it won't be nice.